# The file "x.png" was not uploaded due to an unknown error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to store a file with the move function in laravel, but I get this error : The file "x.png" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.".
I use this code :

```
$file->move(public_path('/files/'), $file->getClientOriginalName());
```

Thanks.

Comment: add more of your code like the form and the full method of the controller

Comment: Please share more details - does your server's error log tell you anything about that error? Which other debugging attempts did you take?

Answer (score 0):

consider using `$file->store` instead, also the '/' char after files in unnecessary

```
$file->store(public_path('/files'), $file->getClientOriginalName());
```